# Why is my isNaN not working in my if statement

Tags: javascript

new to JS. In the following code, the isNaN isn't working. If you enter a number in the prompt, the FizzBuzz rules work fine. However, if you enter a random string, I expect the isNaN condition to be met. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));

for(let i = 1; i < number; i++) {
  if(isNaN(number)) {
    console.log("Is not a number")
  } else if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz")
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("Fizz")
  } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("Buzz")
  } else {
    console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: ironically your problem is to do with `NaN`, but not the one you're testing for. `number` will be `NaN` (because that's what `parseInt` gives you when the parse fails), and `1 < NaN` is `false`, so the loop never runs even once.

Comment: you are testing the loop with a nan so the loop never runs, you should test if NaN before the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `parseInt` can't parse the string to an integer if will return `NaN`. In your `for` loop you use `number` in the condition `i < number`. If `NaN` is compared to a number using a comparison operator such as `<` or `>` the result will always be `false` and the loop will not run at all, this is why nothing happens when you enter a random string.

To get the result you are expecting You could put the `isNaN` check outside the `for` loop and only run the loop if `number` is not equal to `NaN`.

```js
let number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));
if (isNaN(number)) {
  console.log("Is not a number")
} else {
  for(let i = 1; i < number; i++) {
    if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log("FizzBuzz")
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      console.log("Fizz")
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log("Buzz")
    } else {
      console.log(i)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @RobinZigmond correctly pointed out, when you enter an arbitrary string, `number` will be `NaN`.

For loop basically consists of:

```
for (Initialization, Condition, Increment)
```

Your condition: `let i = 1` is run one time, then your condition: `i < number` is checked, in this case `1 < NaN` which is clearly false, as the condition here is not met, you never enter your for loop.

One way to do what you're trying to do is:

```
let number;
while (!isNaN(number)) {
   number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));
}

for(let i = 1; i < number; i++) {
  if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz")
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("Fizz")
  } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("Buzz")
  } else {
    console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let userInput = prompt("Enter a number");
if(isNaN(userInput)) {
  console.log("Is not a number")
} else {
  let number = parseInt(userInput);

  for(let i = 1; i < number; i++) {
    if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log("FizzBuzz")
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      console.log("Fizz")
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log("Buzz")
    } else {
      console.log(i)
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected (putting the `isNaN` check outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move your first if statement out of the loop. It never gets read, because the expression `parseInt(string) < number` will always return false.

```js
let number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));

if (isNaN(number)) {
  console.log("Is not a number")
}

for (let i = 1; i < number; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz")
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("Fizz")
  } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("Buzz")
  } else {
    console.log(i)
  }
}
```